# spl autoload ignore class that don't exist

Tags: php, spl, spl-autoload-register

I have a simple MVC application in php that maps the first query string to a controller name, second to action and any more as parameters. When autoloading classes it looks for naming conventions with regex which is fine, but it wont load classes that clearly exist.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+Controller$/', $classname)) {
        if (class_exists(__DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname)) {
            //never gets to here, even though the file gets
            //included by the require statement below
        }
    require __DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
    return true;
}
});

//controller and action are "default" and "index" by default
//If a query string is passed, it gets the parts
$controller = $url[0];
$action = $url[1];

$controller_name = ucfirst($controller) . "Controller";
$action_name = $action . "Action";

if (class_exists($controller_name)) {
    $controller_object = new $controller_name($request, $config);
    $controller_object->$action_name();
} else {
    echo "Class doesn't exist : $controller_name";
}
```

Example output:

> url.com/ = Class doesn't exist "DefaultController"
>
> url.com/default = Class doesn't exist "DefaultController"
>
> url.com/test = Class doesn't exist "TestController"

DefaultController exists in the controllers directory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure spl autoload only autoloads when you actually try creating a new class object.

Comment: `class_exists(__DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname)` => you mean `file_exists` or `__DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition calls `class_exists()` function, you meant to check for file:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+Controller$/', $classname)) {
        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname)) {
            require __DIR__ . '/controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
            return true;
        }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
  $controller_object = new $controller_name($request, $config);  
  $controller_object->$action_name();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Class doesn't exist : $controller_name";
}
```